# SAFE Stack - installing pre-requisites

Tags: f#, fable-f#, safe-stack

The [SAFE Stack Documentation](https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/quickstart/) says to install **npm** (amongst other things) as a pre-requisite to build SAFE apps. But the link refers to https://www.npmjs.com where you have to search for packages. **But which ones? What to install?** There are thousands of packages there.

**UPDATE:**
I have just noticed that the npm documentation says that *npm comes bundled with node, & most third-party distributions, by default*. So why does the SAFE Stack documentation show the link to npm? Is there any sense in it?

I have tried to install the **npm** package via NuGet. But whatever I do, running the SAFE standard template in VS ends with a NullReferenceException:

File *helpers.fs*

```
let runOrDefault args =
try
    match args with
    | [| target |] -> Target.runOrDefault target
    | _ -> Target.runOrDefault "Run" //NullReferenceException
    0
with e ->
    printfn "%A" e
    1
```

Entering *dotnet run* through a command prompt opens a console window containing these messages:

```
Starting target 'InstallClient'
.> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD" install (In: false, Out: false, Err: false)
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: undefined
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: undefined
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"~16","npm":"~8"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.19.2","node":"v19.0.0"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-04T11_38_04_408Z-debug-0.log
Finished (Failed) 'InstallClient' in 00:00:02.0540071
```

**UPDATE**:
In line with Tomáš Petříček's recommendation, I installed this version of node.js: *Latest LTS Version: 18.12.0 (includes npm 8.19.2)*

But again, *NullReferenceException* in VS, and the following error messages appear when using the command prompt:

```
Starting target 'InstallClient'
.> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD" install (In: false, Out: false, Err: false)
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: undefined
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: undefined
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"~16","npm":"~8"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.19.2","node":"v18.12.0"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-04T13_19_03_959Z-debug-0.log
Finished (Failed) 'InstallClient' in 00:00:01.9942657

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Build Time Report
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Target          Duration
------          --------
Clean           00:00:00.5118885
InstallClient   00:00:01.9937254   (Process exit code '1' <> 0. Command Line: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD install)
Run             00:00:00           (skipped)
Total:          00:00:02.6111670
Status:         Failure
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Fake.Core.BuildFailedException: Target 'InstallClient' failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These adaptations made it possible to run the SAFE standard template on my PC in line with the [Quick Start guidelines](https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/quickstart/):

1. Pre-requisites:

- The .NET 6 SDK //**OK**
- node.js (>= 8.0) //**OK**
- npm //**do not use this link**
- Azure CLI (optional - required for Azure deployments) //**OK**

2. Continue with guidlines 1 to 6 in the "Create your first SAFE app" section. Use `cmd` for the `dotnet run` command.
3. Look at the **node** and **npm** versions in this error message example:

   *npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.19.2","node":"v18.12.0"}*

   You may have different versions of **npm** and **node**, of course.
4. In line with [this article](https://adamj.eu/tech/2022/03/27/how-to-lock-your-projects-node-js-version/) by Adam Johnson, do this:

   Open `package.json` in the root folder of the template and change the versions of **npm** and **node** accordingly, like this:

   ```
    "private":  true,                  

    "engines": {

        "node": "18.x",

        "npm": "8.x"

    }
   ```

   To suppress warnings, you may add `*.npmrc` file containing the text string *engine-strict=true* next to the `package.json` file.

This answer, however, does not solve the problem why there is a link to npm in the pre-requisites section.

The solution in this answer looks somewhat complicated so if you have got a better idea, it will be fine if you publish it.

**UPDATE 08-Nov-2022**

Instructions telling you how to run/debug a SAFE Stack app in Visual Studio are [here](https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/recipes/developing-and-testing/debug-safe-app/). Then no more problems with *NullReferenceExceptions*.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need to install is [Node.js from the official download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) There are two versions:

- LTS (stable) - version 18 and
- Current (development) - version 19

I previously installed "Current" and then run into various troubles (though different ones than you are reporting). You also seem to have 19 according to the log. I gave up with Current and reverted my setup to the LTS version. So perhaps uninstalling the Node version you have right now and installing Node LTS may help.

Comment: I have figured out some partial answer to this problem and it works even for version 19 (adding 19.x for node into package.json).